# Fastest way to check if the current directory is under mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, zsh

I'm trying to speed up my zsh theme prompt and `hg` checks are a bit slower than `git`'s. That result in a slower prompt to show when using the `hg` plugin.

For `git` we use `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` which is the standard and pretty fast.

For `hg` I've tried to find a similar command but nothing is as fast:

- `hg --cwd $PWD root`
- `hg summary`
- `hg root`
- `hg -q stat`

All these commands work but are not as efficient as `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree`.

Also tried this little script which is the best one currently. Anything I can do to speed this script even more?

```
is_dir_hg() {
  local root="$(pwd -P)"
  while [[ $root && ! -d $root/.hg ]]
  do
    root="${root%/*}"
  done

  echo "$root"
}
```

Note that the solution must detect `hg` directory even when we're not in the root directory.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt you can do much better than your script unless you write a compiled program that does the equivalent.

Git's test, using `git rev-parse`, is coded in C and compiled to a simple binary and hence runs very quickly.  Mercurial's is coded in Python, so you pay the Python startup overhead.  Moreover, any extensions you load in Mercurial require searching extension paths and additional run-time loading, which makes Mercurial more flexible than Git, but slower.

If `hg root` were fast enough, you could just run both `hg root` and `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` (and then maybe resolve symbolic links if desired) and see which one is closer to the current directory (again with symbolic links resolved), if both succeed.  Presumably you already tried this and it was not fast enough.

You can resort to your own path-searching, as you did in the sample code.  Instead of *just* searching for `.hg`, however, you could search for both `.hg` and `.git`, and stop when you find either one.  There are many prompt libraries for many shells and several of them use this approach.

All methods are a bit error-prone, especially because it is possible to have a Git repository within a Mercurial repository and vice versa (e.g., `/path/to/current/working/dir` might be Mercurial at the `current` level and Git at the `dir` level, or vice versa).  Meanwhile, the presence of a `.git` directory is not sufficient to *guarantee* that you are in a valid Git work-tree.  For instance, Git believes a directory is a repository only if:

- It can find the Git directory itself (perhaps using `$GIT_DIR`; Mercurial does not seem to have an environment variable override the way Git does; if no `$GIT_DIR`, start at the current directory and climb as needed); and
- the found Git directory contains a file named `HEAD`; and
- the found directory contains a `refs` directory; and
- `$GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` points to a directory, or the found directory contains an `objects/` directory.

The climbing-towards-root search normally tests for, and stops at, mount points, so that if `$HOME/foo` *is* a Git repository, but your current working directory is `$HOME/foo/bar` and this is a mount point and this is *not* a Git repository, Git will not detect `$HOME/foo` as a repository.  A simple in-shell path search would detect `$HOME/foo` as a repository.

Mercurial, by default, just looks for the `.hg` directory in each parent directory, so you are on much firmer ground here.

Note that you can even have a single directory that has both `.hg` and `.git` subdirectories, with both being valid repositories (I have done this for experimental purposes; it works, it is just a bit tricky: you will want to ignore the other VCS's VCS-control files).  That's probably not something you need to handle, which is good since there's no right obvious right way to handle it. :-)

Comment: After many tests and searches, this little script seems to be the fastest of what I can do for now. It's actually significantly faster than what I had before so that will do for now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I’d use `hg id`, which sets the return code usefully as well.  At least it’s fast to type :-)